# Error con sessiones con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un error con el login que no puedo resolver.

bloque.php

```
class General extends Basededatos {

   public function login(){
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = :email AND pass = :pass";
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email'], ':pass' => $_POST['pass']));
            $fila = $stmt->fetchAll();

            if($fila > 0){
                $_SESSION['logueado'] = "SI";
                $_SESSION['usuario']  = $fila['nombre'];
                header('location: ../');
            } else {
                echo 'Email o Password incorrecto';
            }
         } else {
            echo 'Ingrese su email y password';
        }
    }
   }

   public function getUsuario($user){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = ?";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($user));
    
    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $resultado;
   }
}
```

index.php

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logueado'] != "SI"){
header('location: login');
exit();
}

include_once('bloque.php');

$blok = new General();

$nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'];

$user = $blok->getUsuario($nombre);
```

**Errores**

Notice: Undefined index: nombre in...

Notice: Array to string conversion in..

Error `echo 'Hola'.$user;` => Hola Array

Cuando hago `var_dump` de la variable `$user` me dice que el `array` es `0`
`var_dump($user);` => `array(0) { }`

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($nombre);` y verifica si ese usuario existe en la tabla.

Comment: El resultado es `NULL`, pero la tabla `usuarios` existe.

Comment: Ya, pero `$nombre` es `NULL`, debes verificar por qué es `NULL`. Observa que `$nombre` es el criterio que pasas a `getUsuario()`, es lógico que si le pasas `NULL` no encontrará a nadie.

Comment: El siguiente paso de depuración entonces es que hagas un `var_dump($_SESSION);` para verificar lo que hay en tu variable de sesión.

Comment: En la tabla no dice que nombre sea NULL

Comment: Relee mis comentarios y dime si entendiste lo que te quiero decir ¿? No ha dicho nada de **la tabla**. He dicho que los datos que estás manejando, en este caso `$nombre`, tomado de la variable de sesión, es `NULL`. Por tanto, verifica tu variable de sesión.

Comment: Perdon, comprendo. El resultado de `var_dump($_SESSION);` es array(2) { ["logueado"]=> string(2) "SI" ["usuario"]=> NULL }

Comment: Mil disculpa, pero no estoy logrando comprender que esta pasando.

Comment: Te aconsejo que conozcas a ese amigo llamado `var_dump`, **cuando algo no funcione, úsalo**. Yendo al problema, aquí puedes ver dos cosas, la primera es que en tu variable de sesión no hay una clave  `nombre`, por tanto, esto no tiene sentido: `$nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'];`; segundo, vemos que en la variable de sesión sí hay una clave `usuario`, pero su valor es `NULL`. Entonces, debes decidir qué datos necesitas poner en la variable de sesión, ¿`nombre` o `usuario`? Y luego revisar dónde llenas la variable de sesión ¿?

Comment: El problema está ahora en `login()`, de nuuuevo, usa allí `var_dump($fila);` para ver lo que hay ahí. No lo olvides, cuando algo no funcione, revísalo con `var_dump()`. Si aprendes a depurar tu código te vas a ahorrar muchas horas rompiéndote el coco.

Comment: Deberia pasar `usuario` y al hacerlo el error cambio a `Notice: Array to string conversion in...`

Comment: Pasar `usuario` no sirve. Hemos dicho que tiene un valor `NULL`. Lee mis últimos comentarios. Ahora tienes que revisar lo que está ocurriendo el `login()`, haciendo un `var_dump($fila);`

Comment: Perdon que pregunte esto, pero como hago un `var_dump($fila)` en `login()`?

Comment: En el archivo `bloque.php`, vas al método `login()` que tienes ahí, y debajo de esto: `$fila = $stmt->fetchAll();` pones **temporalmente** esto: `var_dump($fila);` de modo que puedas verificar si la consulta está funcionando, qué datos trae y cómo los trae.

Comment: Ah si, crei que deberia llamar a la clase. Pero no me da ningun error o dato.

Comment: Pues define cómo tiene que estar montado tu código. Se supone que desde algún punto llamas a `login()` ¿no?, que ahí verificas si el usuario es válido y llenas la variable de sesión. Entonces, ¿desde dónde llamas a login()`

Comment: Si, y ahora me da este error: `Hola NULL NULL array(2) { ["logueado"]=> string(2) "SI" ["usuario"]=> NULL } `

Comment: Te recomiendo que estudies un poco tu código para que comprendas lo que estás haciendo. Por ejemplo, no sé de dónde sale ese `Hola` y los `NULL` por todos lados indican que tu código no está bien conectado. Analiza punto por punto cada paso, lo que ocurre, qué archivos llamas en cada acción etc. Este tipo de errores no son complicados, **el mayor problema aquí es que no entiendes tu propio código ni como está interconectado**. Eso es lo primero que deberías hacer, luego, encontrar cualquier error será simple.

Comment: `Hola NULL` es el resultado de un `echo 'Hola '.$user;` pasa saber si me imprimia el nombre del usuario. Bueno, voy a ver como resuelvo esto, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unos de los problemas esta aqui

```
<?php
....
$fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){...
?>
```

y en el index deberia estar asi

```
<?php

$id = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$usuario = $blok->getUsuario($id);

echo 'Hola '.$usuario['email'];

?>
```

Aqui `$fila = $stmt->fetchAll();` no estras contando los usuario y por eso que tu resultado es `Null` y luego haces esto `$fila > 0`.

En cambio aqui `$stmt->rowCount() > 0` cuentas si hay registros y si es mayor a `0` entonces hara el llamado.

Pruébalo y me cuentas!

Comment: Sobre usar `rowCount` para determinar el total de filas en una consulta `SELECT`, el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) dice claramente lo siguiente: *«Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement asociado **fue una sentencia SELECT**, algunas bases de datos podrían devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo, **este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables**.»* Significa que no es una buena práctica usar `rowCount()` para esto.

Comment: Gracias a ambos, pero @A.Cedano cual sería una buena práctica?

Comment: @Sebastian, para el caso de `fetchAll()` puedes verificar los mismos datos. Por ejemplo haciendo esto `$fila = $stmt->fetchAll();` puedes saber si hay registros haciendo algo así: `if($fila) { #Hay datos } else { #No hay datos }`, esto es posible porque `fetchAll()` te crea un array con los resultados. Si no usas `fetchAll()` entonces tendrías que verificar con un `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`